# Standard images/data path on an operating system?

Tags: java, image

As in the title, is there a standard path where to store images on an operating system?

For example, in Java you can get the "temporary folder" using **System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")**, is there a similar way to get a path for images?

If not, is there at least a path for generic data storage?

I'm writing a program that generates .pngs that have to be stored, but I want a standard path where to store them until the user chooses his own folder in the settings menu;

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Simply use your own system property.

Comment: Why not just use the temp directory that's already provided anyway?  Everyone has different conventions on how they organize their files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a OS independent path for storing images. Especially with all the unix distributions this might vary from case to case. It also might change based on the localization of the OS. The best way I'd say would be to ask the user where to store the images OR get the users home directory and then store it in a folder called like your program so it is clear to the user where this folder comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the user choose where to save them to begin with, then I would recommend **either**:

- **Don't save anything to their system without their explicit say-so**; that is, don't save anything to the disk anywhere until they select a location for it to go, or
- **Save it to the temporary folder until they select a specific location to store the image**.  This way, your code will be generically portable; where specific files live varies between people, but a temp directory is universal.

Comment: Your first point seems to contradict your second one. When would it be better to choose the first option?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:  Disk space being one concern; if I don't have enough disk space to save the file then I lose it.  Also, it violates the principle of least surprise; if I don't want to save the files after all and there's a bug in which the files aren't cleaned up, then all of a sudden I'm using disk space in a state that I didn't expect to.  Here, it makes that very clear and apparent.

Comment: If a program dies and the file is lost, I can imagine how grateful the user would be that they weren't surprised by the image still being there when they restart the program.

Comment: I'd say we're making strong assumptions about the application.  However, I stand by my original remarks; saving something when it's not expected (or worse, saving it to a path that they didn't initially select) is poor UX.

Comment: I am one of those people who would rather not lose work than possibly waste a bit of space.

Comment: So Office applications saving work in the background is bad UX?

Answer (score -1):

normally the current working directory is used

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

or you can use a relative directory of the home directory

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Pictures");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

Comment: What if I told you I don't have a `Pictures` folder?  What if I wanted those pictures to live somewhere else?

Comment: @Makoto it can create one and if you wanted to store them somewhere in particular you might want to "chooses his own folder in the settings menu"